# Play Framework 2 Scala WS Doing a Sync Request

Tags: scala, concurrency, playframework, playframework-2.0

I am learning Scala. I used to use Play Framework 2 Java and trying to rewrite some of my previous work using and learning Scala.

I need to do a sync WS request and get Result Object from it somewhere in my code.

While I was back in Java, I used to do it like this:

```
WS.url("someurl").get().get(5000);
```

or with `T Promise<T>.get(Long timeout)` to be exact.

Since I switched to Scala, I am now using `play.api.libs.ws` and I rewrote code as:

```
val somefuture:Future[Response] = WS.url("someurl").get();
```

But I can't get **Response** from **Future[Response]** syncly! There is no `.get()` method on scala.

How can I get `Response` object from `Future[Response]` syncly?

Comment: Blocking is not a good idea, you should write your code in a non-blocking way. See Christopher’s answer.

Comment: @JulienRichard-Foy When you have a website app, and the request depends on what the WS returns to use it anywhere like a DB or another WS call, that request thread will have to block.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `Await.result`.

```
import scala.concurrent.duration._
import scala.concurrent.Await

....

val future: Future[Response] = ...
Await.result(future, 10 seconds): Response
```

Answer (score 2):

Use .map and return an asynchronous result. Check out this example:

https://github.com/TechEmpower/FrameworkBenchmarks/blob/master/play-scala/app/controllers/Application.scala#L44

Comment: But `Async` builds an `AsyncResult` from a `Future[Result]` only. It seemed to me that the OP wanted a more generic approach.