# Do async GET like in a loop but wait for response for each

Tags: scala, asynchronous, playframework, playframework-2.0, call

I've googled this and cannot find an answer.

I want to make a GET to a url in Scala/play framework and then do something with the result. If the result contains what I want then I want to call it again with some other parameter. And this could be up to like 100 times so I can't nest several WS's. I want like a loop to do the same call over and over again till I find what I'm looking for but when I wrap all this code below in a loop it dosen't wait for each call to finish, which i understand. But how can I solve this?

```
var index = 0

val call = WS.url("http://urlToGetSomethingFrom&parameter="+index).get()

for{

response <- call

} yield{

  val something: String = response.json / "name"

  if(something.equals("Eric")){

    //I'm finished, break out

  }else{

    index += 1

    //and then I want to do the same call again
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`get()` returns a `Future`.
In order to wait for it to finish, you need to pass it to `Await.result` along with an expiration duration.

Example here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16296848/604041

Comment: Since you were the first one with a working example I'm gonna mark it as the right answer. Thank you

Comment: Thanks. — @The guy who down voted my answers: You could at least explain why.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is basically the same as @MartinGotzke's answer.  I haven't actually tried to compile this or anything, but hopefully it helps ...  Good luck!

```
   /** Keep looking until you find Eric */
   def findEric( index:Int ):Future[Response] = {
        WS.url("http://urlToGetSomethingFrom&parameter="+index).get(
          ).flatMap( 
            (resp) => if( resp.json / "name" == "Eric" ) Promise.successful( resp ).future
                   else findEric( index+1 )
          )
   }


   findEric(0).onComplete( (resp) => { /* whatever it is you really want to do */ } )
```

Comment: You can replace `Promise.successful(x).future` with `Future.successful(x)`

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution that does not use blocking.
The key is that it's using a recursive call and that it uses flatMap and returns Promise.pure for the desired result.

As it's an actually working sample using the old google search api, it's a little bit more complicated because there's a list/Seq of titles that's mapped and checked against the predicate function.

```
package controllers

import play.api._
import play.api.mvc._
import play.api.libs.concurrent.Promise
import play.api.libs.json._
import play.api.libs.ws.WS
import scala.concurrent.Future
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

object Application extends Controller {

  def index = Action {

    def callWS(index: Int, f: String => Boolean): Future[String] = {
      WS.url("https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/web")
        .withQueryString(("v", "1.0"), ("q", "foo" + index)).get
        .flatMap { response =>
          val titles = (response.json \ "responseData" \ "results" \\ "title")
          titles.map(_.as[String]).find(f(_)).map(Promise.pure(_)).getOrElse(callWS(index + 1, f))
        }
    }

    Async(callWS(0, _.contains("FOO-1")).map(Ok(_)))
  }

}
```

Comment: This is something to aim for, non blocking. Will have a look at it! Thank you

Comment: Btw, an issue I see with this/my approach is that the recursion uses the stack (not tail recursive obviously) and thus does not really scale. For s.th. like 100 "loops" this won't be a problem (if you don't reduce the stack-frame size / -Xss significantly), but it will run into a StackOverflowError at some point...

Comment: You can exchange stack for heap using trampolines. See e.g. http://apocalisp.wordpress.com/2011/10/26/tail-call-elimination-in-scala-monads/

Answer (score 0):

Here's another example written in Scala by the Play team for the Techempower benchmarks

https://github.com/TechEmpower/FrameworkBenchmarks/blob/master/play-scala/app/controllers/Application.scala#L44

Comment: Thanks for another example!